# Why python returns scientific notation when calculate in the dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, math, scientific-notation

when I do the calculations in the dataframe using Python, it returns the scientific notations results...Is there method making the results without scientific notations (just return the float)? Those highlighted number should be 0.

[image]

Thanks for the help.

Comment: Do you want to round them ? Or just get the full float ?

Comment: I need the full float. But those highlighted numbers should be 0. I have no idea why Python returns those format...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option1: You can use one option:  `display.precision`: `pd.set_option('precision', 5)`

> [Options and Settings](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/options.html)

Option2: You can use float format:

```
pd.options.display.float_format = '${:,.5f}'.format
```

Option3: you can use the round:

```
DataFrame.round(decimals=0, *args, **kwargs) to can round close to the nearest number:

df.round(5) # for whole dataframe
```

> [pandas.DataFrame.round](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.round.html)

Comment: Yes, in all the cases keep the decimal to 5 and you can change the way your requirements. Mostly I use display.float_format and works all the time.

Comment: Got it. Thanks!